# How to check whether the given AWS Credentials have access to the given arn

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I need to check whether the given AWS Credentials have access to the particular Action to access particular ARN(aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:{accountId}:userpool/{userpoolID}) using java SDK....

If I execute ListUsers with the userpoolID it shows AccessDenied Exception to this ARN..... But I need know is it accessible before executing ListUsers....

Execption I faced:
User: arn:aws:iam::{accountId}:user/{userName} is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:{accountId}:userpool/{userPoolId} (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;)

Comment: This is why `try...catch` block exists.

Comment: Yes, instead of executing the commands and checking whether we have access or not ...  I need to find it through passing ARN

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to do what you want.

Comment: You could try to use the following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html#policies_policy-simulator-how-it-works. However this is not recommended to use before every call to an AWS service, because it is too much overhead to perform some sort of preflight request each time. I would just handle it with standard exception handling instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html#policies_policy-simulator-how-it-works. However this is not recommended to use before every call to an AWS service, because it is too much overhead to perform some sort of preflight request each time. I would just handle it with standard exception handling instead.

Answer from
– [Martin Löper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10473469/martin-l%C3%B6per)